# Ensuring world curving shader is not affected by object scale

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I've made a shader shown below which essentially acts as a "world bend / curve" shader by "bending" objects depending on their position from camera. It's a subgraph that outputs value for vertex position.

It works, but I am seeing strange behaviour on some items, they seem to bend much more than others despite being in a same position. After some digging around I figured out that it is due to some items having different scales. For example object with scale of 1,1,1 bends correctly where as object with scale like 1,0.2,0.5 bends either more extremely or less.

Is there a way to edit this shader so that it takes different scales into account and bends all objects in same manner despite their scales?

Parameters here are

`CurveX` - How much to curve in x axis
`CurveY` - How much to curve in y axis
`Curve Start Distance` - How far from camera should curving effect start from

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose 'Inverse Model' in 'Transformation Matrix' node instead of 'Model' in your shader and hit the 'Save Asset' button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).